# Native JPA Query is giving syntax error when running

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

### When I run the following piece of code (Build is successful) , I am getting the following error

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select t.id, t.webcrt_job_id, t.component_id, t.shop_id, t.frame_id,"
    + "t.job_number, t.job_description, t.status, t.customer_name, t.receipt_date, t.shipment_date, " 
    + " t.cpm, t.comments, t.drawing_number, t.creation_date, t.created_by, t.last_updated_date," 
    + " t.last_updated_by, t.turbine_serial_number, t.is_delete, t.job_type, t.location_id, "
    + "t.copics, t.is_received"
    + "from (select t.id, t.webcrt_job_id, t.component_id, t.shop_id, t.frame_id,"
    + "t.job_number, t.job_description, t.status, t.customer_name, t.receipt_date, t.shipment_date, " 
    + " t.cpm, t.comments, t.drawing_number, t.creation_date, t.created_by, t.last_updated_date," 
    + " t.last_updated_by, t.turbine_serial_number, t.is_delete, t.job_type, t.location_id, "
    + "t.copics, t.is_received"
    + ", row_number() over (partition by job_number order by last_updated_date desc) rn"
    + "from brs.events t ) t where rn = 1 and t.component_id IN :componentId "
    + "and t.status IN :status and t.shop_id IN :shopId")          
List<Event> findUniqueJobNumber(@Param ("componentId") Collection<Long> componentId,
    @Param ("shopId") Collection<Long> shopId, @Param ("status") String status);
```

---

The error I am getting:

```
2017-01-26 15:47:19.891[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m54980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-9000-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"
  Position: 365
[2m2017-01-26 15:47:20.075[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m54980[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-9000-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"
  Position: 365
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jar:9.4.1208]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2003) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jar:9.4.1208]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:200) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jar:9.4.1208]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:424) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jar:9.4.1208]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:161) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jar:9.4.1208]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jar:9.4.1208]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2117) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1967) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:118) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:82) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several instances where you are missing a space:

```
"t.copics, t.is_received" + "from (select t.id, t.webcrt_job_id, t.component_id
```

Every time you line break make sure there is a space included in the string.